# Pycharm Install packages failed: Installing packages: error occurred. error

Tags: python

When I try to install any packages I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZgOn.png). Before I was able to download. However, now I am getting

```
Install packages failed: Installing packages: error occurred. error.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try clicking the details link in your image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer here,

https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-install-python-packages-in-pycharm-without-anaconda-f78c0fe33362

How to Solve Error Messages While Installing Packages in PyCharm

- If an error occurs while installing a package in PyCharm, it may be due to a new version of the “pip” package on your computer. You have to update it before a package will install.
- **To update “pip”:**

1 - Go to “Project Interpreter.” Click on it. Find “pip” among the listed packages. Click on it once, and “pip” will be highlighted. On the right-hand side of the page, you will see an eye-like image. When you hover on it, it displays “Show Early Releases.”

2 - At the top of the eye-like image, there is a faint arrow pointing up. It displays “Upgrade” when you hover on it. Click on the arrow to upgrade “pip” to the latest version. Wait for the upgrade to finish.
After the upgrade is finished, search for the package you want to install as explained above.